# how to trim or replace whitespaces of value which is returning from database pl/sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting a data from database, where one column consists of value with white spaces (example:`55 22 44 88 9997`).

I want to trim white spaces to compare with my data.

My value is `string a="552244889997"` , I'm comparing this value with values in db,
but in db it consists of whitespaces `55 22 44 88 9997`.

Please help me fixing this issue in code behind asp dotnet.

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "55 22 44 88 9997";
a = a.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: the data is coming from DB table.column.columnname,you mean i want save table value into a string ,will it work?

Answer (score 0):

string a = "55 22 44 88 9997";
a = a.Replace(" ", "");

Get data from DB and remove white space:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string cmd = null;
cmd = "select col1 from table";
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
conn.Open();
adp.Fill(dt);
conn.Dispose();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
    string b = Strings.Replace(dt.Rows(0)("col1"), " ", "");    
}
```

Comment: the data is coming from DB [table.column.columnname],you mean i want save table value into a string ,will it work?

Comment: @shivumtyri : I have update my answer with sample of data from DB